# Unexpected Error at #include Statement

Tags: c, xcode, xcode6, c-preprocessor

### Question

I am trying to implement a network interface on top of BSD sockets when I `#include <arpa/inet.h>` Xcode generates a error `Expected identifier or '('` Error at `#include` Statement.

---

### Code

snc_network.h

```
#ifndef __lib_Syncrology__snc_network__
#define __lib_Syncrology__snc_network__

#include "snc_def.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>//Error Here:Expected identifier or '('
//Type Definations

typedef union
{
   struct sockaddr_in6 in6_addr;
   struct sockaddr_in in_addr;
   struct sockaddr addr;
}snc_sockaddr_t;

#endif /* defined(__lib_Syncrology__snc_network__) */
```

snc_def.h

```
//Preprocessor Definations
#define __SYNCROLOGY_VERSION_NUMBER__ 0.0.1;



//Type Definitions



//Padding
typedef unsigned char snc_pad_t;

//Private;
typedef void snc_prv_t;

//snc Data Sturcture
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t sncprot_id;
    uint16_t sncprot_ref; //Refence Count
}snc_struct;

//Application Data
typedef struct
{
   void *data;
   size_t data_size;
}snc_appdata_t;

//Functions

//Null
bool snc_null(snc_struct *sncstruct);

//Reference Count
bool snc_retain(snc_struct *sncstruct);
void snc_release(snc_struct *sncstruct);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 0.0.1 on #define __SYNCROLOGY_VERSION_NUMBER__ 0.0.1;
 that has also a wrong semicolon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly due to the errant semicolon on the line

`#define __SYNCROLOGY_VERSION_NUMBER__ 0.0.1;`

And, **never** use a macro starting with two underscores. That's undefined behaviour in C. Fix that macro, and your include guards.

And, **never** end a variable with `_t` if you're targetting POSIX: they are also reserved.

Answer (score 1):

This definition

```
#define __SYNCROLOGY_VERSION_NUMBER__ 0.0.1;
```

is wrong,

First of all it shall not have a semicolon. And secondly there is no such type of pp-token like `0.0.1`

Comment: I did google but still do not know what pp-token means. Could you please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even Though  semicolon for the line "#define **SYNCROLOGY_VERSION_NUMBER** 0.0.1; " is unnecessary, it should not give compilation errors right ?

try defining  inet.h before snc_def.h  ...  :)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "snc_def.h"
```